# Неправильная подсветка ошибок импортов в PyCharm. Discord бот на hikari

Tags: python, pycharm

**Структура (коренным каталогом является `app`):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для примера содержание `wr_sqlite`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главным запускаемым файлом является `application.py`, поэтому никаких ошибок во время работы не возникает. PyCharm подсвечивает эти импорты как ошибку, но хотелось бы избавиться от этого и приобрести возможность навигации по пространству имён в самом коде.

Пишу Discord бота. В `application.py` при помощи вызова определённого метода у объекта бота импортируются все нужные модули. Если в импортируемых модулях (и в импортах у импортируемых модулей) не прописывать импорты "от лица" `application.py`, то ничего не работает. Вот если что используемый [враппер под Discord API (hikari)](https://github.com/hikari-py/hikari), а здесь [фреймворк для менеджмента команд (lightbulb)](https://github.com/tandemdude/hikari-lightbulb).

`application.py`:

```py
bot = lightbulb.BotApp(<...>)

bot.load_extensions_from(<...>)
bot.load_extensions(<...>)
```

Comment: По идее `wrappers` это модуль, попробуйте в его каталог поместить хотя бы пустой файл `__init__.py` для начала.

Comment: Это помогает только при относительном импорте (`impot ..<>`). В данном случае это всё запускается "от лица" главного файла, но IDE это не понимает

Comment: Вы бы не умничали а сделали как вам советуют, ещё хотелось бы увидеть дескриптор того что подсвечено.

Comment: Я то сделал как мне советуют, поэтому и говорю что это не работает. Да это и не должно работать

Comment: Откуда ваш wr_sqlite.py знает про builder.py ?

Comment: В данном ввиде у вас не будет работать нечего, если вы попытаетесь использовать wr_sqlite.py

Comment: Можно конечно програмно добавить модули в sys.path но это уже другой разговор, и поэтому скорее всего PyCharm матерится.

Comment: @Александр читайте вопрос. Запускаемым файлом является `application.py`,  от "его лица" прописываются импорты (т.к. фактически в его пространство имён это всё импортируется). Если запустить как main `wr_sqlite.py` ничего работать и не должно

Comment: Честно говоря, я с импортами и сам до сих пор несколько "плаваю". У меня тоже были ситуации, что либо `IDE` не ругается, но скрипт файлы не находит, либо скрипт всё находит, зато `IDE` не видит импорты и подсвечивает. Питон в этом плане, конечно, заумный какой-то.

Comment: Мдам. С работой программы всё нормально, но хочется удобства при навигации через среду. Возможно стоит написать JetBrains куда-то на фидбэк (или эта функция где-то есть), чтобы можно было указывать с какой позиции будет запускаться файл

Comment: Ещё зависит от версии Python, раньше вроде бы нужнен был __init__.py в пакете сейчас не обязательно.

Comment: Я не знаю как, но добавление перед импортами имени корневой директории проекта (в которой находится `application.py`) всё исправило, по крайней мере при нескольких тестовых запусках

Comment: Попробуйте пометить главную директорию (mark as) как Source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Проблему решил перенос главного запускаемого файла на уровень с каталогом `app`.**

Новая структура:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    wrappers/
        __init__.py
        wr_sqlite.py
        ...
    builder.py
application.py
```

Теперь во всех импортах в проекте сначала указывается директория `app`, пример `wr_sqlite`:

```py
from app.wrappers import wr_json
from app.wrappers import <...>
```

PyCharm не ругается и при обычной работе всё идеально работает.